# jQuery show submenu on hover and add class if submenu exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I want to show submenu when menu li is hovered such that: when .nav has a ul.submenu and .nav li is hovered, show .submenu and add class .arrow-down, and onmouse out hide it again.

My HTML is as follows:

```
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Facilities</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Coaching</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Performance Tests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Trainers</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Coaching</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Performance Tests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Membership</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Coaching</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Performance Tests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Schedule</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Coaching</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Performance Tests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks...

Comment: [The wheel - no need to reinvent it](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul.nav > li').hover(function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').show();
        $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
    }
},
function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    }
});
```

Comment: updated this to add my own code: //navigation
   $('ul.nav > li').hover(function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
     $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
        $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
    }
},
function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul.submenu').length > 0) {
        $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    }, this), 200));
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    }
});

Comment: ^ above features a timer and a slide up and down feature.